# Reduce gap between bars in svg graphs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am working on a stacked bar chart. here is the codepen https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/NWvZGLd

The result of codepen looks as below. As you can see, the width is too long and i want to make the barchart compact and fit inside a 50% width. Basically, i want to reduce the gaps between each bars so that the width of the barchart automatically gets reduced after that.

Can someone please let me know how to reduce the width between the bars which are side by side each other. i tried reducing the bar gap by changing the width, x and y properties as below but was only able to achieve final result as shown in codepen.

```
<rect
  width={20}
  height={height}
  fill={bar.color}
  x={100 + rowIndex * 60}
  y={490 - y - height}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decrease the x-axis index of `rect` and `text`

```
return (
      <>
      <g key={Math.random()}>
        <rect
          width={20}
          height={height}
          fill={bar.color}
          x={100 + rowIndex * 30}
          y={490 - y - height}
        />
        <text
          x={110 + rowIndex * 30}
          y={490 - y - height/2}
          dy="0.5em"
          textAnchor="middle"
          style={{ fill: 'white', fontSize: '12px' }}
        >{`${bar.color === '#ffcc00' && bar.value === 100 ? 'X': bar.value}`}</text>
         <text
            x={105 + rowIndex * 30}
            y={480}
            textAnchor="end"
            style={{ fill: 'red',
              fontSize: '13px',
              transformOrigin: (125 + rowIndex * 30)+'px 480px',
              transform: 'rotateZ(-45deg)'
            }}
          >{entry.name}</text>
        </g>
      </>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `x` position. You need to understand your own variables.

```
const gutter = 30; // Instead of 60 currently

// ...
<rect
  width={20}
  height={height}
  fill={bar.color}
  x={100 + rowIndex * gutter}
  y={490 - y - height}
/>
```